# How to open Firefox container links in "No Container" - Automatically

Tags: firefox

This is a question for those familiar with the two Firefox add-ons:
Multi-Account Containers and Temporary Containers.

Normally if you open a page in a container, and click a link on the page, it will open a new tab in the **same** parent container.

But if you have the extension Temporary Containers installed, you can right-click the link and choose to open it in a "No Container". Now the new tab will open in the **Default** Firefox container, just like any other tab.

I am looking to do the above automatically, i.e.:
1. When I open a tab in a container. 
2. And open a page in that container, and click any link.
3. It should **automatically** open in the Default Firefox container (not in the parent container, and not in any other container).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. I did not find it, a good person shared it with me.
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/container-outgoing-links

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2022, you can do this without installing any additional addon.

> Assuming you're using the official Multi-Account Containers addon,
> click on "Manage Containers" in that addon's popup, then on the
> container you want this to work on (e.g., the "Social Media" container
> in your example), then select "Limit to Designated Sites".

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/kj2nt8/comment/ggvuhmo/